# Best practices when creating 2 Jars (Portable and Dependency) in Maven

Tags: java, maven, portability

I created a small tool to sign PDF's. Now I would like to have 2 Jars, one Portable Jar where you can just execute the Jar and thats it and a Jar which can be loaded into other projects and used.

My current approach:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>BatchPDFSign</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>BatchPDFSign.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

As you can see my first approach was to create an Uber Jar with the maven-assembly-plugin and the normal Jar with the maven-compiler-plugin.

But I don't loose the feeling that I've done it totaly wrong and there is a much better way to do this. I am quite new with maven.

tl;dr: what is the best way to create a Jar with all the dependencies and a Jar suitable to be uploaded to maven in one swoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you would create a multi-module project with two modules:

- The library.
- The executable jar.

The executable jar uses the library as dependency and adds what is needed to run it (probably a Main class and some configuration).

Then the library can also be used by anybody else.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier And the library jar should be a normal one and the executable a fat jar right?

Comment: Yes, that is how it should be.